# Get notification on video chat invitation

Tags: php, yii, videochat

I have developed an application and i have APIs to create video calls. currently my problem is if some one invites other persons to chat, how can i generate a notification for invitees? I am using PHP and MySQL for developing the application. currently i am thinking i should work this way: While inviting, a DB insertion will happen, i should check for this insertion with small interval (may be of seconds). If the person is invited, then he will get notification. Is this the usual practice? Please advice

Comment: Any one know how can i integrate `longpolling` with Yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. Do not know if this is the best practice. I created a function to check any database change. I used `setinterval` to repeat the function with an interval of 5 seconds. And it did work :)

Comment: do you mean to use JavaScript's `setInterval()`?